# Inflate exception occurs 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-appcompat

I am trying to upgrade my gradle. When i updated the appcompat from 1.0.2 to 1.1.0, my webview didnt work anymore on certain phones. (api 21 and 22).
Is there a smart way to upgrade to 1.1.0 and still make the webview work.

I get an 'android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class '. 
I have tried to find a way to update the webview on my emulators. But i really hope for a code that either way fixes the problem, for users that dont update the webview.

my xml:

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

My Activity:

```
 private WebView mWebView;
    private String state;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.login_webview_activity);

            mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

            WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);

            mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

My error:

```
WebViewActivity: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at no.posten.sporing.controller.activity.WebViewActivity.onCreate(WebViewActivity.java:53)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
```

And again- appcompat 1.0.2 works like a charm, but not 1.1.0.

Comment: Something might be wrong with your xml. Please share the related xml code too.

Comment: @Meyben... I am also facing the same issue... Any solution?

Comment: haven't found any solution yet... just ended up with downgrading appcompat again hahah

Comment: It's a bug in Lollipop + regression in AppCompat 1.1.0, see: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141132133 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025200

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are not relying on DayNight theme switching (or other [UiMode events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager)), you can add `android:configChanges="uiMode"` to the webview activity manifest to prevent AppCompatDelegate updating the Resources configuration and thereby messing up the webview inflation. Found this workaround by [studing the sourcecode](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/26079d87c79a64829f036236353fac1dae4e0613/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegateImpl.java#2269) of the 1.1.0-rc01 to 1.1.0 changes.

Downgrading to 1.1.0-rc01 should also work.

Comment: Wonderful and elegant answer.