# WebView throws InflateException on android 5.0

Tags: android, android-webview

After upgrading to `"androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"` and `"com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01"` the WebView crashes on devices with Android 5.0 and throws this exeption `android.view.InflateException`

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView

How can I fix it?

Comment: post your code and log for better understanding of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58131421/9125569), this issue is due to the [this revision](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/26079d87c79a64829f036236353fac1dae4e0613%5E%21/#F2). It affects Lollipop devices with webview version<50. Use the following code as a solution.

```
override fun applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration: Configuration?) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT in 21..25 && (resources.configuration.uiMode == AppConstants.appContext.resources.configuration.uiMode)) {
                return
        }
        super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about your targetSdkVersion and your buildTools version? Once I had a very similar issue. I started seeing this exception when I raised the targetSdkVersion to 25 and the build tools to 25.0.2.

Also try to update your app theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant). Change your AppTheme parent to Theme.MaterialComponents.

Example

**Before:**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

**After:**

```
 <!-- Material application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```