# How use Android webview in fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, webview, fragment

HomeFragment.java

```
package com.example.starcitizen.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.example.starcitizen.R;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public HomeFragment(){ }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        String url = "http://google.com";
        WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_webview);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return rootView ;
    }
}
```

fragment_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.starcitizen.fragment.HomeFragment">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/home_webview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I looked at other questions. but my app is not works.
So I wonder if I need to fix my main activity. So I attached the main activity.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.starcitizen;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_guide, R.id.nav_maps,
                R.id.nav_ships, R.id.nav_weapons, R.id.nav_mission)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Sorry I'm not good at english. So with help of a translator...
and I asked stackoverflow for the first time.

---

I'm working on an app for koreans. but I have some problem in fragment.

If a webview is entered, App will be turned off without running.

please help me.

add logcat!

---

11-15 20:00:31.465 3666-3666/com.example.starcitizen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.starcitizen, PID: 3666
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.starcitizen/com.example.starcitizen.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at com.example.starcitizen.fragment.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:18)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2624)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:904)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at com.example.starcitizen.fragment.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:18) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2624) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:904) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2040003
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:385)
        at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore

---

Tried to understand but failed..

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Use "match_parent" instead of "wrap_content" in your WebView's width and height

Comment: Can you describe more about the issue, maybe you have error in logs in logcat?

Comment: https://inducesmile.com/android-programming/how-to-show-webview-in-fragment/ may help

Comment: I found logcat! but I don't understand this. I added it to the post.

Comment: I first knew it was a logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no difference to use `WebView` in `Activity` and `Fragment`.

I can't figure your troubleshooting but I recommend you to check the following things.

1. check the permission in manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2. check if there is `Runtime` Exception in `onAttach()` of  `HomeFragment`.
3. If you wanna see the `WebView` in `Fragment`, you should declare the following code.

```
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

> Update

```
    final String source = "http://google.com";
        final WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_webview);
        //webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                //Do some like progress bar loading here.

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl(source);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But still not working. I tried 1, 3 .
I don't know where the error comes from.. No error in build, but error on the phone..

Comment: I found logcat! but I don't understand this. 
I added it to the post.

Comment: Can you let me see the activity_main.xml file?

Comment: It runing when I put a button or text in the post. But only webview is not running

Comment: What is the target sdk version? If it is more than Oreo, you should try to use WebView like the following code that I updated.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I fixed it for now! There was an error with the Gradle version.
I use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025200/android-view-inflateexception-error-inflating-class-android-webkit-webview/49024931