# Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView on android 5

Tags: android, webview, android-appcompat, androidx

I got the following error testing on Android 5.0 (API 21). Tested on other OS versions works well.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{...ui.activities.navigationActivity.fragments.legalFragment.LegalDetailActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error
>   inflating class android.webkit.WebView

Can't find nothing special about the xml layout, at line 24:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/nav_fg_legal_detail_web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  />
```

The code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar)
    setContentView(R.layout.legal_detail_activity) // crash here. Nothing done to web view yet.
```

I am using library 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'.

**Update**:
the full stack:

```
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.byte_artisan.mchat2, PID: 4198
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.byte_artisan.mchat2/com.byte_artisan.mchat2.ui.activities.navigationActivity.fragments.legalFragment.LegalDetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.byte_artisan.mchat2.ui.activities.navigationActivity.fragments.legalFragment.LegalDetailActivity.onCreate(LegalDetailActivity.kt:18)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.byte_artisan.mchat2.ui.activities.navigationActivity.fragments.legalFragment.LegalDetailActivity.onCreate(LegalDetailActivity.kt:18) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2040002
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:274)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:360)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.setContainerView(ContentViewCore.java:702)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.initialize(ContentViewCore.java:608)
    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.createAndInitializeContentViewCore(AwContents.java:619)
    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.setNewAwContents(AwContents.java:758)
    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(AwContents.java:608)
    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(AwContents.java:546)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.initForReal(WebViewChromium.java:312)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.access$100(WebViewChromium.java:97)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$1.run(WebViewChromium.java:264)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue.drainQueue(WebViewChromium.java:124)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue$1.run(WebViewChromium.java:111)
    at com.android.org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread(ThreadUtils.java:144)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue.addTask(WebViewChromium.java:108)
    at com.android.webview.chro
```

Comment: Does the device have an up-to-date "Android System WebView" installation? On Android 5.0, IIRC, that "app" provides the guts behind `WebView`.

Comment: I just pull the simulator image.Guess not.

Comment: And can't install it, because the simulator has not google play installed.

Comment: Funny, getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.software.webview") says it is installed but it now show on app manager.

Answer (score 16):

24 April 2020, I solved it with this:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-beta01'
```

*Previous and **not working** version is below:*

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

Comment: where to add it?

Comment: Add in build.gradle (Module: App)

Answer (score 7):

Recently I faced the same, There is an issue which is mentioned over [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141132133), which is not solved yet. The crash only occurs on API 21.

There are few solutions which mention downgrading the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` versions. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49024931/8809599) helped me. Also, there are other possible workarounds mentioned, pick the answer that applies to you.

EDIT: The crash also occurs on API 22 and 23 if the user doesn't have Google Play installed.

EDIT 2: As mentioned in the issue tracker [here](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141351441#comment35), and upgrading the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` version to **1.2.0-alpha02** is providing the fix in some cases. Please go through a detailed discussion to find a suitable workaround.

As mentioned by @MiguelSlv adding [this](https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6052626/androidx_snapshot/latest/repository/) maven repository is a temporary fix, However, all the above workarounds have side effects. As the bug is not fixed yet, it is not a clean solution.

**EDIT 3:** As of May, 2020, there is a fix.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-beta01'
```

Previous not working version:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Not sure the issue you mention is the same. In your issue the crash is about a resource. i don't see it on my stack error.

Comment: I think it is similar, please see the other issue and discussion, it is concluded that 1.2.0-alpha02` fixes it. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141351441#comment35

Comment: @MiguelSlv I guess you are facing similar issue from stack track it is clear `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID` kindly check with the solution provided, I guess it would help

Comment: @Sam. kindly update answer with the point you have mentioned in the comment

Comment: alpha01 doesn't fix it for me. I try to use then alpha02 but, for some reason, gradle can't find it. i added maven repository 'https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/6052626/androidx_snapshot/latest/repository/'. Modifying the constructor can have some side effects.Still looking for a clean solution for my case.

Comment: I have updated the answer, the bug is from 2016 and it is still not fixed, so all the solutions are workaround solutions.

Answer (score 5):

This answer I am writing in **Mar, 2020**, could be changed after that.

In my case , in `build.gradle (app level)`, I changed

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha02'
```

and the Problem is solved.

**Other configuration I already have, but I didn't change them:-**

1. In Gradle project level

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

2. And in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

3. And in `gradle app level`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    ...
}
```

Noting that this solution is tested on real device with android version 5

Comment: thanks for comment... developers who want latest stable version can look this link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.appcompat/appcompat?repo=google

Comment: I used latest androidx... still problem occur  have not solved

Comment: @ Beyaz: if the answer is not working for you, it doesn't not mean it's wrong. as it solved my problem and already up voted by other 2 developers. thanks for understanding

Comment: Dear @Atef, I have over ten apps ... All of my apps have crash problem for android 5.1 ... You are telling it worked for you... but you are wrong... I'm still trying fix this bug

Comment: @ Beyaz: I understand your feedback. appreciated.

Comment: Dear @Atef ... maybe  it is fixed with implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha02  but I used latest one androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-beta01  where I found  from this address https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.appcompat/appcompat?repo=google  But it is weird .. if it is fixed with alpha but occur in beta ??? I will test your suggested implemention and will see result... I'm trying fix this crash nearly for two week... did a lot effort

Comment: I edited my answer for complete configuration I have.

Answer (score 0):

I have over ten apps,  All of my apps have "Inflating problems" I was trying to solve problems...  And I  have tested with emulators and  real device,  they have no crash ... But My user  thus!
Finally  while testing with emulator , I catched crash.. Here is result:
This answer writing with 19 April 2020:

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-beta01
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha03
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha02
```

above  versions  have Serious problems.... Creating dialog, cause Edittext or TextView inflating problems...

below versions  have been tested  a little but there were no crash

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha01
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0
```

Still testing this versions , will share results

Comment: any testing results?