# (< API 24) NavigationView Error (inflating class) (works in API24+)

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

So I have a problem with devices that are below API 24. My code works in API 24+

I always get an error when I try to set the layout of my NavDrawer:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);
```

Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_nav_drawer"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_drawer_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MANIFEST (Theme):

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Changed the AppThme no it gives me this error from the Fragment.
Again its loading the layout and gives me this error:

The line where the error occurs is a Webview

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.streamdev.aiostreamer/com.streamdev.aiostreamer.NavDrawer}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at com.streamdev.aiostreamer.ui.HQPFragment.onCreateView(HQPFragment.java:69)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2624)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:904)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at com.streamdev.aiostreamer.ui.HQPFragment.onCreateView(HQPFragment.java:69) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2624) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:904) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2040003
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
        at android.conten
```

My activity main.xml (all fragments uses this one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#202020"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#202020"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/adview"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#202020"/>

            <com.streamdev.aiostreamer.ui.ExpandableHeightGridView
                android:id="@+id/customgrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/os_texts"
                android:background="#202020"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                android:listSelector="#00000000"
                android:numColumns="2"

                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp">

            </com.streamdev.aiostreamer.ui.ExpandableHeightGridView>

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/adview2"

                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:background="#202020"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <LinearLayout


        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/searchtext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:hint="Search..."
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchbutton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you post you error?

Comment: I changed the AppTheme now it shows me a new error in the Fragment that it tries to load, check in original post

Comment: Is this the error?      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2040003

Answer (score 0):

Your first line of the error showing that below view is the reason of the issue.

```
 <com.streamdev.aiostreamer.ui.ExpandableHeightGridView
            android:id="@+id/customgrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/os_texts"
            android:background="#202020"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:numColumns="2"

            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp">

        </com.streamdev.aiostreamer.ui.ExpandableHeightGridView>
```

Comment: I am using this class because I couldnt position the webview like i want. they always sticked to the bottom and top. so i found the solution with a scrollview and a gridview: https://gist.github.com/Kishanjvaghela/248b86b9e1c9fbcb8cd7#file-expandableheightgridview-java

Comment: Are you sure that it is this class? Because line #29 refers to the Webview...

Comment: I disabled the WebView and my app opens now, i dont know why? Are WebViews not supported in lower APIs?

Comment: webviews are supported in all version.

Comment: Only putting the webview in the xml crashes the app, that´s ridiculous. I am not even doing sth. with it. I read that it might be an emulator error but actually people telling me it doesnt work for android 4-6

Comment: I found this one but nothing worked yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025200/android-view-inflateexception-error-inflating-class-android-webkit-webview

Comment: No but i fixed it I think, the LollipopFixedWebview helped out I guess! Might be an error inside the API itself