# crash when focus input in webview android

Tags: android, webview, crash

first login my website in webview successfully but for second login crash app when focus input username, this is error when crash:

```
W/ResourceType: Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0x02080003
        Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0x02080003
    W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Atteenter code herempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getPadding(android.graphics.Rect)' on a null object reference
            at org.chromium.ui.DropdownPopupWindow.<init>(DropdownPopupWindow.java:80)
            at org.chromium.ui.autofill.AutofillPopup.<init>(AutofillPopup.java:48)
            at org.chromium.android_webview.AwAutofillClient.showAutofillPopup(AwAutofillClient.java:50)
            at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
            at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:37)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
    A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Check failed: false. Please include Java exception stack in crash report
    W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
        Chrome build fingerprint:
        1.0
        1
        45012863-7d3b-4c30-8ccf-e65394c57d85
        ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
    A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9115 (ir.aysan.bis)
    Process 9115 terminated.
```

Comment: The following answer on Stackoverflow for changing appcompat to 1.2  (old 1.1) solved our problem -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57968071/2641380

Answer (score 0):

It's a WebView crash happened on android 5.0\5.1,

try to **close text autocomplete**

```
 <input type="text" name="symbols" autocomplete="off" />
```

Happy coding.....