# App crash while trying to start new activity in onCreate method on android 5.0 device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview

Please I have checked for possible solution but unable to find any.
I have a web view app which I start new activity in `onCreate`, everything is working fine on other android `Android 6.0` and above, you on `Android Version 5.0` Huawei my app crashed with bellow errors.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(!AppController.getInstance(this).getHandShake()) {
            //At first launching
            Intent gettingStarted = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GettingStarted.class);
            gettingStarted.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            this.startActivity(gettingStarted);
        }
        //Continue loading website url in main activity
         if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            webviewapp.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }else{
            webviewapp.setWebViewClient(new MainActivity.customWebViewClient());
            webviewapp.setWebChromeClient(new MainActivity.customWebChromeClient());
            appLoadUrl("https://example.com", false);
        }
 }
```

Am not unable to figure out what the problem is.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.application.example, PID: 27705
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.application.example/com.application.example.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2406)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:152)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.HwPhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(HwPhoneLayoutInflater.java:75)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:701)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:760)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:825)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:935)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:523)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:368)
    at b.b.k.k.l()
    at b.b.k.h.setContentView()
    at com.application.example.MainActivity.onCreate()
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6013)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3040002
    at android.content.res.HwResources.getText(HwResources.java:1252)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:374)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.setContainerView(ContentViewCore.java:948)
    at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.initialize(ContentViewCore.java:848)
    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.createAndInitializeContentViewCore(AwContents.java:649)
    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.setNewAwContents(AwContents.java:788)
    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(AwContents.java:635)
    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(AwContents.java:573)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.initForReal(WebViewChromium.java:315)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.access$100(WebViewChromium.java:100)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$1.run(WebViewChromium.java:267)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue.drainQueue(WebViewChromium.java:127)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue$1.run(WebViewChromium.java:114)
    at com.android.org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread(ThreadUtils.java:144)
    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium$WebViewChromiumRunQueue.addTask(WebViewChromium.java:111)
    at com.android.webview
```

Comment: There appears to be some issue with `WebView` on that device. It is unlikely to be related to your code. Make sure that the device has all available updates applied.

Comment: This will help you
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57968071/5417056)