# WebView Crash on Android 5-5.1 (API 21-22) Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2040002

Tags: android, android-webview

I am in the process of updating an Android app from API 27 to API 29 and I noticed that I get a crash when trying to render a WebView on an emulator based on 5.0 and/or 5.1. This issue does not happen on an emulator running 6.0 or higher (API 23-29).

I cannot seem to find any documentation about WebView behaviour that would affect 5.0 or 5.1 but I can confirm the problem doesn't happen when I run the app using API 27. I am at a loss as I don't know if this is an emulator problem or an actual API/device issue (I am thinking the latter).

The issue is the Activity and Fragment won't inflate at all, due to a missing String resource. Here is some of the stacktrace (it can't seem to find a String resource):

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.example.MyWebView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.example.MyWebView...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException...
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2040002
```

Before the crash happens, there is some related warnings in the logs related to the resource:

```java
W/chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(315)] locale_file_path.empty()
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
W/chromium: [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(901)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
W/chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(403)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
W/ResourceType: No known package when getting value for resource number 0x02040002
```

**WebView:**

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {

    public MyWebView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    public MyWebView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    public MyWebView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize();
    }

    public MyWebView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        initialize();
    }

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, boolean privateBrowsing) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, privateBrowsing);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        this.clearCache(true);
        this.clearHistory();
        this.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        this.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        this.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(false);
        this.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(false);
        this.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(false);
        this.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(false);
        this.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(false);
        this.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        this.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(false);
        this.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(false);
        this.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
        this.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            this.getSettings().setSafeBrowsingEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <com.example.MyWebView
        android:id="@+id/my_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or what may have changed in API 28 or 29 that could break this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.view.InflateException Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025200/android-view-inflateexception-error-inflating-class-android-webkit-webview)

Comment: same happening with me but it's a duplicate question.

Comment: Wow, I am having the exact same crash with the emulator running Android 5.0.2, but a physical device running Android 5.1 runs without any issue. As the answer @DmitryBrant posted above, the issue is not with API 28 or 29 but with `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0`, if you downgrade to `1.0.2` or `1.1.0-beta01` that crash should disappear.

Comment: @Seven Are you sure it is working fine on physical device ! Because I don't have physical device of API level 21 to test!

Comment: @SumitShukla yeah, I am sure. It worked fine in my physical device running Android 5.1 (Moto G 1st Gen).

Comment: This has been fixed as of 1.2.0-alpha02

Answer (score 24):

I went through the same trouble and actually what solved it was changing the context in the constructor to `context.getApplicationContext()`.

After that it's building and rendering with no problems on Android 5.

Comment: Beautiful. This fixed it for me `LayoutInflater.from(activity.applicationContext).inflate(layoutResId, null)` instead of using `activity`

Comment: it works for me but what is  the difference between context  and getapplicationContext?  why it does not work for lollipop?

Answer (score 18):

It seems to be a bug with appcompat 1.1.0 - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141132133

While you can try downgrading appcompat or wait for a fix, you can also try

Using a custom WebView:

```kotlin
private fun Context.getLollipopFixWebView(): Context {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT in 21..22) {
        createConfigurationContext(Configuration())
    } else this
}

/**
 * Workaround appcompat-1.1.0 bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141132133
 */
class LollipopFixWebView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyle: Int = 0) :
    WebView(context.getLollipopFixWebView(), attrs, defStyle)
```

Or adding this workaround to the parent Activity of your WebView:

```kotlin
    // Workaround appcompat-1.1.0 bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141132133
    override fun applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration: Configuration) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT in 21..22) {
            return
        }
        super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration)
    }
```

Credits and kudos to https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/issues/5507
There the guy believes it's happening to Android 7 as well but I couldn't replicate

### Updates

The custom WebView solution may introduce a new problem: keyboard not showing for all Android versions.

So we'll need to set `isFocusable` and `isFocusableInTouchMode` to the custom WebView class prevent such problem

```kotlin
class LollipopFixWebView : WebView {
    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context.getLollipopFixWebView(), attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        isFocusable = true
        isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    }
}
```

### Disclaimers

My `minSdk` version is 21 (Lollipop) so can't guarantee my solution works for apps with lower minSdk version

Comment: overriding applyOverrideConfiguration worked for me!

Comment: Thank you. The solutions are working well. Just wondering if there is any potential risk to override the _applyOverrideConfiguration_ function.

Comment: Be careful not to use the WebView context when retrieving any attributes from the theme, because the newly-created context will not have them.

Comment: @ericn upgrading to implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-beta01 solved the issue, would be any side effects of it on the above versions(6.0 and above)

Comment: I've done all the testing I could and found no problem so far. I don't think there's a way to know 100% for sure @Girish

Comment: Thanks for not using Lollipop version of constructor with `defStyleRes: Int`. In this case it is called even in API 19 and crashes. So, you just didn't add it and it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 12):

Fixed in `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha02`
Just update your app `build.gradle` file with line:

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha02"
```

Comment: Updating to 1.2.0-alpha02 fixed this issue but introduced different ones. Ended up doing a workaround @ericn mentioned below

Comment: @user3783123, could you say, what bugs have appeared? Was the advice of Gunnar Bernstein helpful?

Comment: @user3783123 upgrading to implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-beta01 solved the issue, is there any side effects of it on the above versions(6.0 and above)

Comment: @Girish it somehow broke the app's change language (locale) functionality on android 6.0 and below. Didn't have time to research how and why it happened though

Comment: @user3783123 is that the only thing that broke or any other?

Comment: @Girish it was the only thing that stopped working in our case

Answer (score 8):

It seems to be a bug with appcompat 1.1.0 - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141132133

Looking at #30 in that discussion, this solved my problem:

```
// add to gradle module:app
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    }
}
```