# Determine WebView Implementation (System WebView or Chrome)

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, android-7.0-nougat

Android 7.0 allows users (via developer options) to choose the implementation of their WebView. The user can choose the standalone WebView or use the Chrome APK to render WebViews. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#webview)

Since this potentially means those who use WebViews now have two different code bases to worry about, it would be useful to know which implementation is currently selected.

**Is there a way to determine what WebView implementation is selected in Android 7?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like this now available in Android O Preview:

Link: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/managing-webview.html

> Starting in Android 7.0 (API level 24), users can choose among several
>   different packages for displaying web content in a WebView object.
>   **Android O includes an API for fetching information related to the
>   package that is displaying web content in your app**. This API is
>   especially useful when analyzing errors that occur only when your app
>   tries to display web content using a particular package's
>   implementation of WebView.
>
> To use this API, add the logic shown in the following code snippet:
>
> ```
> PackageInfo webViewPackageInfo = WebView.getCurrentWebViewPackage();
> Log.d(TAG, "WebView version: " + webViewPackageInfo.versionName);
> ```

WebView.getCurrentWebViewPackage Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getCurrentWebViewPackage()

Comment: Also there is `WebViewCompat.getCurrentWebViewPackage()` which works on L+

Answer (score 4):

To get the current Android `WebView` implementation and version I've created this method which should be valid for every API level.

```
@SuppressLint("PrivateApi")
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "JavaReflectionInvocation"})
public @Nullable PackageInfo getCurrentWebViewPackageInfo() {
    PackageInfo pInfo = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        //starting with Android O (API 26) they added a new method specific for this
        pInfo = WebView.getCurrentWebViewPackage();
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        //with Android Lollipop (API 21) they started to update the WebView 
        //as a separate APK with the PlayStore and they added the
        //getLoadedPackageInfo() method to the WebViewFactory class and this
        //should handle the Android 7.0 behaviour changes too
        try {
            Class webViewFactory = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebViewFactory");
            Method method = webViewFactory.getMethod("getLoadedPackageInfo");
            pInfo = (PackageInfo) method.invoke(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        //before Lollipop the WebView was bundled with the
        //OS, the fixed versions can be found online, for example:
        //Android 4.4 has WebView version 30.0.0.0
        //Android 4.4.3 has WebView version 33.0.0.0
        //etc...
    }
    return pInfo;
}
```

Then you can evaluate the result

```
if (pInfo != null) {
    Log.d("WEBVIEW VERSION", pInfo.packageName + ", " + pInfo.versionName);
}
```

> Remember: Immediately after an app update of WebView, a crash
>   could appear as described here:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/29809338/2910520, at this moment, this line `webViewFactory.getMethod("getLoadedPackageInfo")` of the code above would return null. 
>   Actually there is
>   nothing you can do to prevent this, (this should not happen if the WebView implementation is taken from Chrome app but is not confirmed).

Comment: For the second approach (Lollipop until Oreo) you have to make sure that "WebView has already been loaded into the current process". If no WebView is initialized `getLoadedPackageInfo` will return null.

Comment: Currently there is no way to know when the WebView is loaded. That's why the code is inside a try-catch. Maybe we could add a delay to perform the check to have more chances the WebView has been loaded. I can assure you I'm having the same problem even if I call only public API, for example calling WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw() as first thing in Application, I've reports on CrashLytics of background exception related to this :(

Comment: @MatPag Can we safely assume that this is only a matter of time, before a WebView implementation is wired into the current process? I experience occasional crashes on RuntimeException in an activity inflating WebView, when started via a PendingIntent from notification.  Do you think adding a delay might help? Thx

Answer (score 2):

As a supplementary info to [the answer of DataDino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42934761/1083957), for APIs below 26 here's a chunk of code that would give the desired output:

```
    Class webViewFactory = Class.forName("android.webkit.WebViewFactory");
    Method method = webViewFactory.getMethod("getLoadedPackageInfo");
    PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) method.invoke(null, null);

    if ("com.android.webview".equals(packageInfo.packageName)) {
        // "Android System WebView" is selected
    } else {
        // something else selected
        // in case of chrome it would be "com.android.chrome"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an appCompat version:

`WebViewCompat.getCurrentWebViewPackage(context)`

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {

    // ...
    implementation 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.4.0' // Add to your gradle

}
```

```
public static String WebViewPackageName(Context context) {
    PackageInfo webViewPackageInfo = WebViewCompat.getCurrentWebViewPackage(context);
    return webViewPackageInfo.packageName;
}
```